# How to install @types from an NPM package that has @ in it's name

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I can install this node package

```
npm install @gamestdio/timer --save
```

However, when I try to install the types which go along with it

```
npm install @types/@gamestdio/timer --save
```

The result is

```
Invalid package name "@types/": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, try `@types/__gamestdio/timer`

Comment: That didn't work for me, but I'll keep looking around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use yarn

```
yarn add @types/@gamestdio/timer
```

or manually add to your `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/": "gamestdio/timer",
  }
```

then remove your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again